# Append text files with Multiselect using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The goal is to use the multiselect function to load multiple plain text files, one after the other in the same worksheet. They need to be each below the other. I managed the code to load them properly one by one, but I'm stuck with the MultiSelect thing.

The code does append the files, but one next to the other (let's say horizontally) and not vertically as I need. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Prova_Multiselect_Click()
    Dim Fitxers As Variant
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim destCell As Range

    Set destCell = Worksheets("PEDREC").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Fitxers = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Choose txt files", FileFilter:="Text files *.txt (*.txt),")

    If IsArray(Fitxers) Then

        Set destCell = Worksheets("PEDREC").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1) 

        Msg = "Files selected:" & vbNewLine

        For I = LBound(Fitxers) To UBound(Fitxers)

            With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Fitxers(I), Destination:=destCell)
                .TextFileStartRow = 1
                .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            End With

            Msg = Msg & Fitxers(I) & vbNewLine

        Next I

        MsgBox Msg

    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected."
    End If
End Sub
```

I couldn't find the way to append all the files in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't advancing destCell at all while you were looping, leaving it permanently stuck in A2. Try:

```
      For I = LBound(Fitxers) To UBound(Fitxers)


        With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & Fitxers(I), Destination:=destCell)
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        Msg = Msg & Fitxers(I) & vbNewLine

        Set destCell = destCell.Offset(1, 0)


      Next I
```

Comment: Hi Werrf, thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but it doesn't put the text files in the same column as I need, and still places each file in a different column. Yet, with your code, every file is one single row below the precedent file, but still in different columns.

Comment: You put me on the track. I modified the line in your code: ""Set destCell = destCell.Offset(1, 0)"" for the one used in the beginning of my code ""Set destCell = Worksheets("PEDREC").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)"" and now it seems to work. The answer was right in front my nose. Thanks again for your help!